# I’m having trouble with the structure/order of this script

Tags: lua

I’m new to Lua programming and i want to try a script where you make input from user when print(”type your name:”) appear, i got that to work, but im having trouble with the rest when checking the number for which category the age does fits in, for example if the user do input age a number between 0-4 it will return (”I’m baby”) and ”baby” will be replaced based on the number age input from user. If someone can change the script for me and explain a simplier way of doing this. Im trying my best to explain my issue, i will post a picture of my code script. Thanks for reading.
Best Regards. Viktor

Script:

[image: 1]

Comment: That's code I posted in an answer recently. awefully put together without understanding a thing. there is no simpler way, you just have to do it right. as is that code doesn't do much

Comment: why do you post that code as a screenshot? post the code as text....  the order is incorrect and it clearly showas that you do not understand a thing. please start with a beginners tutorial then come back to the problem you want to solve

Comment: I suggest next time you don't delete my answer so we can both refer to it. I invest valuable time of my life to help you and you just throw it away, just to come back later and asking for help on the same problem again.

Comment: Thanks for losing my motivation to continue learn programming, i will never know how to complete that script, i must complete that script before i move on.

Comment: Everyone starts as a beginner, you did it maybe a 10 years ago i started a couple a days ago, its like everything else you wanna learn, you ask for help from the people that know the answer.

Comment: I don't want you to lose your motivation. I'm just annoyed by the fact that I explained something to you and instead of adding a comment to my answer, aksing to clarify something, or posting a new question that links my answer you delete my answer and basically ask the same thing again. now I have to type everything again from a screenshot. that's just a matter of respect. nevermind. I'll give the correct order. give me a second

Comment: Also the answer you provided below, i understand zero of  speaking programming language, need to write it in a way that a beginner understand.

Comment: The reason i posted a picture of the code instead of a text is becuase i posted this from my mobile and the code is in my computer and im not home, and i wanted a solution until i got home, been stuck on this script for 2 days. I know its better to post the code in text i apologize for the picture.

Comment: I suggest you start with pen and paper. write down: 1. enter age, 2. find age in age table 3. create age table.  -> this should immediately make you think: hey how can I find the age in a table that I have not created yet?  programming wise I would suggest that you start with the very basics. if you cannot make sense of the code I gave you last time, you need to research what the things are and how you use them. what is a function? what happens if I do not provide, but use arguments? what is a logic operator `== ` and what does it do? why do I use it here? does it make sense? question yourself

Answer (score 1):

Your code with some comments:

```
print "Type your name:"
inputName = io.read()

-- inputName == inputName is always true!
-- it is the same value checking this makes no sense
-- hence this if statement is pointless
-- you should rather check wether a name was entered
if inputName == inputName then
print("Hi! " ..inputName)
end

print "Type your age:"
inputAge = io.read()
-- here you index the table ageClass which has not been defined yet
-- this will cause an error. you cannot use tables that do not exist yet.
print("I'm " .. ageClass[age])

-- now you define a local table ageClass
local ageClass = {}
-- fill it with values
-- some for loops...
-- then you define a global function with the same name

function ageClass()
-- function body
end

-- now you can no longer use the table ageClass
-- this calls the function ageClass but you do not provide an age
-- this will cause an error for comparing a nil value with a number!
ageClass()
```

Correct order:

1. define a table or a function that converts an integer age to a string. you do not need both.
2. read the age, make sure you convert it to a number if you want to use it as a number table key or function argument (you cannot compare numbers with strings)
3. convert the age to a string like "baby" using the function or the table, whatever you defined.

Comment: lol i have trouble when i make a space it automatically send the comment... wait

Comment: print "Type your name:"
inputName = io.read()

-- you should rather check wether a name was entered

if inputName == inputName then
print("Hi! " ..inputName)
end

If i input Viktor it says Hi! Viktor, if i input Calzone it says Hi! Calzone.

if rather check wether a name was entered, i doesnt work...

if inputName == ”Viktor” it wont print if i input another name thats why i use inputName == inputName

Comment: I dont know why every text got together...

Comment: And now it got canceled nice

Comment: but do you undestand that inputName and inputName are the same variable? a variiable is always equal to itself. checking that doesn't make any sense. you could for example check if it is not an empty string and that it is actually a string. for the beginning it should suffice to check wether it is a string and that it is not an empty string `if inputName and inputName ~= "" then ...`

Comment: I understand but what should i do instead of == same variable

Comment: If i do inputName == ”Viktor” i can’t input another name

Comment: Ok i”ll try that

Comment: Type your name works correctly now, but i still dont understand how im going to write the rest of the code with the table etc, for example do i only need a table, i can skip function?

Comment: print "Type your age:"
inputAge = io.read()

print ("I'm " .. ageClass[age])

local ageClass = {}

for i = 0, 4 do ageClass[i] = "baby" end
for i = 5, 12 do ageClass[i] = "kid" end
for i = 13, 19 do ageClass[i] = "teen" end
for i = 20, 64 do ageClass[i] = "adult" end
for i = 65, 100 do ageClass[i] = "old" end

function ageClass(age)

    if age < 5 then
    return "baby"

    elseif age < 13 then
    return "kid"

    elseif age < 20 then
    return "teen"

    elseif age < 65 then
    return "adult"

    elseif age < 101 then
    return "old"

    end
end

Comment: i have no idea how to write for it to work properly

Comment: lua: practice.lua:11: attempt to index a nil value (global 'ageClass')
stack traceback:
        practice.lua:11: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

Comment: you're using ageClass befor having defined it again... is that so hard to understand that you cannot use elements of a table that does not exist? the interpreter runs the script line by line, it cannot know ageClass befor it is defined